# Getting list of Opportunity Id with apex. (getting an error)

Tags: apex, list

I created a test class and i require to get list of Opportunity Ids,

I got this-

```
       List<Id> oppsIds = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
    OpportunityIntegrationCalls.sendEmptyQuote(oppsIds);
```

And I'm getting an error - `Illegal assignment from List<Opportunity> to List<Id>`

Can`t figure it out :/

Comment: The Query is returning the List of records not the list of the ids. So you have to use list<Opportunity> and then take the ids . by using For loop and adding the id to the list

Comment: At first I had List<Opportunity> - but than i get this error - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void sendEmptyQuote(List<Opportunity>) from the type OpportunityIntegrationCalls (25:37)

Comment: Yes, As your method is accepting the list<Id> . So you have to get the list of records and get the list of ids from it as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query gives the List of records so you should assign it the `List<Opportunity>` as shown below.

And you have to change the code something as below.

```
List<Opportunity> opplist= new List<Opportunity>();
List<Id> oppsIds = new List<id>();
 opplist=[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];

For(opprtunity opp:opplist)
{
oppsIds.add(opp.id);
}
OpportunityIntegrationCalls.sendEmptyQuote(oppsIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is simple, `List<Id>` and `List<Opportunity>` are not compatible, so you cannot assign one to the other. Your query is giving you a `List<Opportunity>`.

Probably the simplest way to get the Ids from a query would be to put the result into a Map (the Map class has a constructor that takes a `List<SObject>`), and then fetch the keyset.

```java
// We can create a map from the result of a query
// Queries with no filters are generally a bad idea, you should have _something_
//   in the WHERE clause to reduce the number of rows you get
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE <some filter(s) here>]);

// The constructors for List and Set can take the other one as input
// Handy when keySet() gives you a set, but you need a list
SomeClass.SomeMethod(new List<Id>(oppMap.keySet()));
```